# jQuery Toggle in and out issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, toggle

I am using the `.toggle` event to open and close content. This is 90% working at the moment.

However I am seeing a undesired issue when I move between states.

**The issue** - I want to be able to complete **step 4** in the journey -

1. I selected *art*
2. Art content is shown
3. I then select *music*
4. **Art content is toggled off and music content is toggled on**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#active-screen').click(function() {
    $('#show-music, #show-art, #show-food').toggle(450);
  });
  $('#active-music').click(function() {
    $('#show-screen, #show-art, #show-food').toggle(450);
  });
  $('#active-art').click(function() {
    $('#show-music, #show-screen, #show-food').toggle(450);
  });
  $('#active-food').click(function() {
    $('#show-screen, #show-art, #show-music').toggle(450);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#" id="active-screen">Screen</a>
  <a href="#" id="active-music">Music</a>
  <a href="#" id="active-art">Art</a>
  <a href="#" id="active-food">Food</a>
</div>

<div id="show-screen">show screen</div>
<div id="show-music">show music</div>
<div id="show-art">show art</div>
<div id="show-food">show food</div>
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you call `toggle()` on all the 'show' elements, so the single displayed item is hidden, but the other hidden ones are shown.

To fix this and DRY up the logic you can use common classes on all the elements. Then you can hide them whilst showing the one targeted in the `href` of the clicked `a`, something like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $show = $('.show');

  $('.menu a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $show.not(this).stop().hide(450);
    $($(this).attr('href')).stop().toggle(450);
  });
});
```

```css
.show { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#show-screen">Screen</a>
  <a href="#show-music">Music</a>
  <a href="#show-art">Art</a>
  <a href="#show-food">Food</a>
</div>

<div id="show-screen" class="show">show screen</div>
<div id="show-music" class="show">show music</div>
<div id="show-art" class="show">show art</div>
<div id="show-food" class="show">show food</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, will upvoe this answer! One thing however - in the code snippet I included if I re-select a toggle item it reverts back to the initial state. Similair to a filter  - how can implement this using your DRY method?

Comment: In that case you need to use `not()` to exclude the current item from the hide operation and then use `toggle()`. I've updated the answer for you

Comment: This is nice, however the intention is for each `div` to be shown by default, as well when I re-select an item. If that make's sense?